# Julia on multiple machines with different data

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a large data that I cannot fit in memory of one machine. Therefore I would like to divide them into subsets of different size, place each subset on different machine (or load that subset directly on that machine) and then execute the same code on them on each machine. The master node should just gather data.

This task is probably appropriate for SPARK, but I am curious if there is a framework that would allow me easily do this in Julia.

Comment: I think Distributed Array (DArray) is exactly what you are looking for, check, related part -> http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs2101a_moreno/Parallel_computing_with_Julia.pdf

Comment: I think this is a fair question and shouldn't be on hold, it's not asking for a recommendation on "the best framework", just wondering if there are tools, libraries, etc to achieve the above. The Julia language is often extended through modules. That being said, @RezaAfzalan has answered your question, and that should be exactly what you're looking for. It used to be part of Julia, but has been moved out.